# How to filter based on the value(tuples) in a pair RDD in terms of key

Tags: apache-spark, filter, rdd

**The sample RDD looks like:**

```
(key1,(111,222,1)
(key1,(113,224,1)
(key1,(114,225,0)
(key1,(115,226,0)   
(key1,(113,226,0)    
(key1,(116,227,1)    
(key1,(117,228,1)   
(key2,(118,229,1)
```

I am currently doing a spark project. I want to filter the first and last elements where the third position in tuple values are `'1'` and `'0'` based on keys.
Is it possible to do it with reduceByKey? But after my research, I did not find a good logic to reach what I want. I want my result in the order which is the same as the output shown below.

**Expected output:**

```
(key1,(111,222,1)
(key1,(114,225,0)
(key1,(113,226,0)
(key1,(116,227,1)
(key2,(118,229,1)
```

Much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you want. The last "1" for key1 seems to be `(key1,(117,228,1)` but you are not keeping it. Is it a mistake or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the first "1", the first "0", the last "1" and the last "0" for each key, and maintain the order. If I were you, I would use the SparkSQL API to do that.

First, let's build your RDD (By the way, providing sample data is very nice, giving enough code so that we can reproduce what you did is ever better):

```scala
val seq = Seq(("key1",(111,222,1)),
    ("key1",(113,224,1)),
    ("key1",(114,225,0)),
    ("key1",(115,226,0)),   
    ("key1",(113,226,0)),    
    ("key1",(116,227,1)),    
    ("key1",(117,228,1)),   
    ("key2",(118,229,1)))

val rdd = sc.parallelize(seq)

// then I switch to dataframes, and add an id to be able to go back to 
// the previous order
val df = rdd.toDF("key", "value").withColumn("id", monotonicallyIncreasingId)
df.show()
+----+-----------+------------+
| key|      value|          id|
+----+-----------+------------+
|key1|[111,222,1]|  8589934592|
|key1|[113,224,1]| 25769803776|
|key1|[114,225,0]| 42949672960|
|key1|[115,226,0]| 60129542144|
|key1|[113,226,0]| 77309411328|
|key1|[116,227,1]| 94489280512|
|key1|[117,228,1]|111669149696|
|key2|[118,229,1]|128849018880|
+----+-----------+------------+
```

Now, we can group by "key" and "value._3", keep the min(id) and its max and explode back the data. With a window however, we can do it in a simpler way. Let's define the following window:

```scala
val win = Window.partitionBy("key", "value._3").orderBy("id")
// now we compute the previous and next element of each id using resp. lag and lead
val big_df = df
    .withColumn("lag", lag('id, 1) over win)
    .withColumn("lead", lead('id, 1) over win)
big_df.show
+----+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+
| key|      value|          id|        lag|        lead|
+----+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+
|key1|[111,222,1]|  8589934592|       null| 25769803776|
|key1|[113,224,1]| 25769803776| 8589934592| 94489280512|
|key1|[116,227,1]| 94489280512|25769803776|111669149696|
|key1|[117,228,1]|111669149696|94489280512|        null|
|key1|[114,225,0]| 42949672960|       null| 60129542144|
|key1|[115,226,0]| 60129542144|42949672960| 77309411328|
|key1|[113,226,0]| 77309411328|60129542144|        null|
|key2|[118,229,1]|128849018880|       null|        null|
+----+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+
```

Now we see that the rows you are after are the ones with either a lag equal to null (first element) or a lead equal to null (last element). Therefore, let's filter, sort back to the previous order using the id and select the columns you need:

```scala
val result = big_df
    .where(('lag isNull) || ('lead isNull))
    .orderBy('id)
    .select("key", "value")
result.show
+----+-----------+
| key|      value|
+----+-----------+
|key1|[111,222,1]|
|key1|[114,225,0]|
|key1|[113,226,0]|
|key1|[117,228,1]|
|key2|[118,229,1]|
+----+-----------+
```

Finally, if you really need a RDD, you can convert the dataframe with:

```
result.rdd.map(row => row.getAs[String](0) -> row.getAs[(Int, Int, Int)](1))
```